# 3 Wire SE Feeder 4 Wire Appliance

Tags: electrical

I have a 50 amp circuit wired with 6 Gauge AA-8000 Aluminum SE wire from the panel that goes to my oven/microwave combo, and then continues on to my cooktop. Both the oven/microwave combo as well as the cooktop have 4 wires. The instructions say wire red to red, black to black, and ground/neutral to the 3rd wire in the feeder, in my case stranded bare aluminum twisted together. I have been doing some research and have been told that bootlegging the ground off the neutral can cause a dangerous situation if something happens for Neutral to float at a hot voltage, now ground is hot too and you lose the protection.

That being said, I have a 50 AMP spa panel, on a different circuit obviously, that is fed by 6/3 cable back to the panel. Is it ok to run a ground from my spa panel with 6 Gauge green sheathed wire, to my oven, then cooktop and use that for the ground, the bare aluminum for neutral, and black to black, red to red, and now have a safe 4 wire circuit?

This wouldn't impact my spa GFCI breaker would it?

Apparently stealing ground from another circuit came was allowed in 2014 NEC from what I have read, but there seems to be a caveat that it must come from a circuit that originates in the same panel. Would this be the case if I connected ground in my spa panel which is connected to my main panel with the oven/range circuit? What if I break into the circuit between the spa panel and the main panel? I don't know why that would be any different however. Whether I do it at point A or point B they are still connected to the same circuit right?

Comment: Great question, welcome to Stackexchange!

Comment: I don’t think you can use bare wire as anything but ground. Too much chance of contacting a ground and that and neutral must not connect except the n the main panel.

Comment: If you can run a ground wire between the spa disconnect and the first box on the oven/cooktop circuit, can you fit like a 1" ENT between the two?  Also, can you post a photo of the breaker for the spa circuit please?

Comment: I could use conduit, but it would be under my house into a short run of conduit up the wall to the spa panel. My understanding is that THHN/THWN wire doesn't need conduit in a crawl space if it isn't susceptible to damage. Did you want a picture of just the breaker, or the panel opened up? the spa panel is just a single 50 amp GFCI breaker on the outside of my house. Conduit running to the spa, and conduit carying the 4 wires back to my main panel. All 6 gauge copper.

Comment: Your understanding on thhn / thwn is wrong it requires conduit in a crawl space or wall.

Comment: @Richard -- THHN *must* be put in a conduit or raceway, no exceptions

Comment: @Richard -- a picture of just the spa breaker in the main panel will suffice (I'm considering your options for moving the spa GFCI to the main panel here, since that's the only thing that needs neutral in a typical spa setup)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think i'm just going to hire someone to pull a new circuit rather than have to worry about it.